# c program for finding the highest divisible number is not working

Tags: c

So I am new to C programming. The purpose of this program is to use a function to find the largest number divisible. Three numbers should be given and the answer should be the number that is higher than the first number and lower than the second number and should be the largest number between them that can be divided evenly by the third number.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int my_function(int first, int second, int third) {
    int i, answer;

    for (i = second; i <= 0; i--) {
        if (i < first || i > third) {
            answer = 0;
            break;
        }
        if (i % third == 0 && i != 0 && i > first)
            answer = i;
    }
    return answer;
}

int main() {
    printf("enter number one:\n");

    int one, two, three, final;
    scanf("%d", &one);

    printf("enter number two\n");
    scanf("%d", &two);

    printf("enter number three\n");
    scanf("%d", &three);

    final = my_function(one, two, three);

    printf("the number is %d", final );

    return 0;
}
```

This program is not working. Can someone help me with my mistake?

Comment: At the very least `printf("the number is %d\n", j);` ... I didn't delve any deeper into your code. Except that `final` is not a valid C type.

Comment: Please indent the code and remove the unnecessary empty lines.

Comment: "this program is not working" => Please tell us what you expect and what you get instead.  What is your test case?

Comment: You don't need a loop for that. Use that the largest multiple of `a` no larger than `b` is `a * (b / a)` for positive numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Your function does not work for multiple reasons:

- the loop test is always false if `second` is a positive number.
- the test `i > third` will cause an early exit from the loop for no good reason.
- when your find a divisible number, you should then exit the loop.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int my_function(int first, int second, int third) {
    int i;

    for (i = second - 1; i > first; i--) {
        if (i % third == 0)
            return i;
    }
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    int one = 0, two = 0, three = 0, final;

    printf("enter number one:\n");
    scanf("%d", &one);

    printf("enter number two\n");
    scanf("%d", &two);

    printf("enter number three\n");
    scanf("%d", &three);

    final = my_function(one, two, three);

    printf("the number is %d\n", final);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: hey thankyou for your answer.the reason for the final is not as a  keyboard but as a integer name.